# A special 4th degree polynomial interpolation with 4 points

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, interpolation

I have 4 points: $(x_i,y_i),\quad i=1,2,3,4$
and $x_i=x_1+i-1,\quad i=2,3,4$
(so these x-coordinates are evenly spaced)

I want to find a polynomial interpolation of these points, having the following form:
$$y=a_4(x-b)^4+a_2(x-b)^2+c$$

I don't know how to solve the parameters. Could you please give me a help?

**Edit**

Sorry for the incorrect usage of "coefficient".
I need to solve 4 unknown parameters, especially $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll adjust your indices down by one. Also, I'll define $z_i := x_i-b$. Finally, I'll write $a_0$ for $c$, for the sake of consistency. Then we have four equations in four unknowns $a_0$, $a_2$, $a_4$, and (the hidden) $b$:
$$y_i = a_4z_i^4+a_2z_i^2+a_0 \qquad i=0,1,2,3 \tag{1}$$

Viewing the first three equations (for $i=0,1,2$) as a linear system in the $a_i$, we can solve to get

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= -\frac{
  y_0 z_1^2 z_2^2 (z_1^2 - z_2^2) 
+ y_1 z_2^2 z_0^2 (z_2^2 - z_0^2) 
+ y_2 z_0^2 z_1^2 (z_0^2 - z_1^2)}{
(z_0^2 - z_1^2) (z_1^2 - z_2^2) (z_2^2 - z_0^2)} \tag{2}\\[6pt]
a_2 &= \phantom{-}\frac{
  y_0 (z_1^4 - z_2^4) 
+ y_1 (z_2^4 - z_0^4) 
+ y_2 (z_0^4 - z_1^4)}{
(z_0^2 - z_1^2) (z_1^2 - z_2^2) (z_2^2 - z_0^2)} \tag{3}\\[6pt]
a_4 &= -\frac{
  y_0 (z_1^2 - z_2^2) 
+ y_1 (z_2^2 - z_0^2) 
+ y_2 (z_0^2 - z_1^2)}{
(z_0^2 - z_1^2) (z_1^2 - z_2^2) (z_2^2 - z_0^2)} \tag{4}
\end{align}$$
(Note that the denominators put restrictions on allowable values of some parameters.) Substituting these into the $i=3$ equation, we find after dust settles:
$$\begin{align}
0 
&=y_0 (z_1^2 - z_2^2) (z_2^2 - z_3^2) (z_3^2 - z_1^2) \tag{5}\\
&-y_1 (z_2^2 - z_3^2) (z_3^2 - z_0^2) (z_0^2 - z_2^2) \\
&+y_2 (z_3^2 - z_0^2) (z_0^2 - z_1^2) (z_1^2 - z_3^2) \\
&-y_3 (z_0^2 - z_1^2) (z_1^2 - z_2^2) (z_2^2 - z_0^2) 
\end{align}$$

Now, upon substituting back $z_i \to x_i-b$, we see that
$$z_i^2 - z_j^2 = (z_i-z_j)(z_i+z_j) = (x_i-x_j)(x_i+x_j-2b) \tag{6}$$
so that, for general $x_i$, each term of $(5)$ has three factors involving $b$ and therefore contributes some multiple of $b^3$ to the overall sum. This makes solving for $b$ possible via the [Cubic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), but the algebra is messy.

Luckily, for equally-spaced $x_i$ (that is, for $x_i = x_0 + i d$ for some $d$), each term of $(5)$ has a factor of $2x_0+3d-2b$, from the $z_i^2-z_j^2$ factor with $i+j=3$; since the denominators of the $a_i$ also have such a factor, we may assume the value is non-zero. This allows us to divide-through by that factor, as well as $d$s that accumulate from $x_i-x_j$ factors, turning $(5)$ into the following quadratic:
$$
\begin{align}
0 &=2 b^2\;(y_0 - 3 y_1 + 3 y_2 - y_3) \\[4pt]
&-\phantom{2}b\phantom{^2}\left(\begin{array}{l}
\phantom{+3}y_0(4x_0+9 d) - 3y_1(4x_0+7 d) \\[4pt]
+3y_2( 4x_0+5 d) - \phantom{3}y_3(4x_0+3 d)
\end{array}\;\right) \\[4pt]
&+\phantom{3}y_0 (x_0 + 2 d) (2 x_0 + 5 d) - 3 y_1 (2 x_0 + 5 d) (\phantom{2}x_0 + d)  \\[4pt]
&+ 3 y_2 (x_0 + 2 d) (2 x_0 + \phantom{5}d) - \phantom{3}y_3 (\phantom{2}x_0 + \phantom{9}d) (2 x_0 + d) 
\end{align}
\tag{7}$$

Taking $x_0=0$, this simplifies to
$$\begin{align}
0 = 2 b^2&\;(\phantom{10}y_0 - \phantom{1}3 y_1 + 3 y_2 - y_3) \\
-3bd &\;(\phantom{1}3y_0 - \phantom{1}7 y_1+5y_2 - y_3) \\
+d^2&\;(10y_0 - 15 y_1 + 6 y_2 - y_3)
\end{align}\tag{8}$$

This quadratic in $b$ is readily solved. Substituting the resulting value(s) into the formulas for the $a_i$ is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

**Example.** If we have points $(0,3)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,4)$, $(3,1)$ (so that $d=1$), we find $$(b,a_0,a_2,a_4) = \left(2,4,-\frac{47}{12},\frac{11}{12}\right) \quad\text{or}\quad \left(\frac{19}{22}, \frac{101789}{108416}, \frac{1109}{336}, -\frac{121}{168}\right) \tag{9}$$
The corresponding polynomials have the following graphs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The last step is so amazing. A perfect quadratic equation, no $b^4$, no fractions. I'll try to derive it by myself.

Comment: With $z_i$, it's much clearer now. Great!

Comment: The expression for $a_2$ seems a little wrong. There should be no minus sign before $y_1$.

Comment: @kevinjwz: Fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x_i$ you have an independent equation, getting to solve
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(x_1 - b)^4 & (x_1-b)^2 & 1 \\
(x_2 - b)^4 & (x_2-b)^2 & 1 \\
(x_3 - b)^4 & (x_3-b)^2 & 1 \\
(x_4 - b)^4 & (x_4-b)^2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a_4 \\ a_2 \\ c \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ y_4 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a basic Gaussian Elimination exercise once the elements of the matrix on the LHS are computed.

**UPDATE**

If $b$ is also unknown, and you can do this in code or in Excel, I would do the following. Using the above equation, define the error function 
$$
f(b) = \|b - Ax\|_2^2
     = \sum_{k=1}^4 \left( y_k - a_4(x_k-b)^4 - a_2(x_k-b)^2-c\right)^2
$$
where the $a_4,a_2,c$ are (numerically) calculated by Gaussian Elimination for any fixed value of $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Now minimize $f(b)$ and you are done.

In other words, for each iteration of the minimizer, given a fixed value of $b$,

1. Solve for $a_4,a_2,c$ using Gaussian Elimination
2. Compute the error $f(b)$

Comment: You can use three of the equations (say, for $i=1, 2, 3$) to solve for $a_4$, $a_2$, $c$ in terms of the $x_i$, $y_i$, and $b$. Then use these in the fourth equation ($i=4$) to get an equation for $b$; namely, a quartic with two linear factors and a quadratic.

Comment: @gt6989b $b$ is an unknown parameter, so I can't just solve it like a ordinary linear equations.

Comment: @Blue Thank you. I tried to calculate the inverse of the first 3 rows of the matrix, using WolframAlpha, and I replaced $x_i$ with $x_1+i-1$. Here is the result: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%7B%7B%28x_1-b%29%5E4%2C+%28x_1-b%29%5E2%2C+1%7D%2C%7B%28x_1%2B1-b%29%5E4%2C+%28x_1%2B1-b%29%5E2%2C+1%7D%2C%7B%28x_1%2B2-b%29%5E4%2C+%28x_1%2B2-b%29%5E2%2C+1%7D%7D)

Comment: @Blue Am I really able to solve for $b$?

Comment: @kevinjwz please see the update

Comment: @gt6989b Please tell me if I understand it wrong. Step 1: Guess $b$, say $\tilde{b}$; Step 2: Solve $a_4=\tilde{a}_4$, $a_2==\tilde{a}_2$ and $c==\tilde{c}$, using the first 3 equations; Step 3: Let $\tilde{y}_i(b)=\tilde{a}_4(x_i-b)^4+\tilde{a}_2(x_i-b)^2+\tilde{c}$, error function $f(b)=\sum_{i=1}^{4}(\tilde{y}_i(b)-y_i)^2$, minimize $f(b)$ (solve $f'(b)=0$ or gradient descent), then go to Step 2.

Comment: @kevinjwz When you program optimizers, the key is to program the error function (which here is $f(b)$), and then apply some minimization algorithm to that function. Steps 1-3 apply to each iteration, but hopefully over time you will guess $b$ more correctly.